# prevent a pseudo element from triggering hover?

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

If I have markup:

```
<div class="a b"></div>
```

where the .a class has a hover class associated with it

and the .b class has a pseudo element associated with it... like so:

```css
div
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.a { background: red; display: inline-block; }
.a:hover { background: green; }

.b:after
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background: pink;
}
```

Is it possible with css to prevent a pseudo element from triggering the .a class hover?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jZ4Sb/)**

Comment: can you provide a snapshot of how you want and what you have?

Comment: Afaik it's not possible because the pseudo element is a child of the real element.

Comment: could the **not** selector help?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The following css does the trick for modern browsers [(not IE10-)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events):

```
.b:after {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

`pointer-events: none` allows elements to not receive hover/click events.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbNy5/4/).

---

**Caution**

`pointer-events` support for non-SVG elements is in a relative early state. [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) gives you the following warning:

> **The use of pointer-events in CSS for non-SVG elements is
>   experimental.** The feature used to be part of the CSS3 UI draft
>   specification but, due to many open issues, has been postponed to
>   CSS4.

**Chrome's box model interpretation of `display: inline-block` causes a flicker in [the above fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbNy5/4/).**
If you switch to `display: block` instead, you will get the proper interpretation of the box.
Firefox does not have this issue.
To ensure consistent box model interpretation, use the following:

```
.b:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
}
```

View [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBRwc/1/) in Chrome to see the flicker effect.

Comment: hmm that's a good idea, but i'm seeing a flicker... any ideas?

Comment: Hrm, I can't see a flicker. Which browser/OS do you use?

Comment: I'm using chrome on windows7

Comment: @tessi I just noticed something: If i hover into .b:after from the *bottom* - then i get the flicker, but if i hover into it from the other directions - i don't get the flicker. go figure.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Chrome (using Linux). Firefox works flawless. Might be a chrome(ium) bug (although I couldn’t find a matching issue in their bug tracker). Conclusion: Better not use `pointer-events` in cross-browser production code.

Comment: @Danield Added a warning for production usage to my answer

Comment: +1 thanks for the edit... and yes you're right - firefox has no flicker.

Comment: In Chrome 42.0.2311.152 if you hover over the bottom edge of disabled `.b` it will still trigger the hover. :(