# Preventing hover on pseudo element - but pointer-events: none; doesn't do it

Tags: css

I have a few links on one line next to each other, and I would like to have dividing dashes between them. I chose to make this happen with the use of the `::before` pseudo element, and it works nicely.

However, hovering over the dividers also triggers the hover over the element I have the `::before` on.

[This is a fiddle showing the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/z64urqxv/3/) If you hover over the dashes, the underline appears under the `a`.

In my search as to how to prevent this from happening, I ran into [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669889/prevent-a-pseudo-element-from-triggering-hover). Together with the [documentation on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) and the [caniusethis page](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) on the pointer-events property I was sure this would fix it. But it didn't.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make changes in css

```
.wrap a::before {
    content: '----';
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.wrap a {
   text-decoration: none;
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 50px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is a cleaner version of the answer that was posted a few minutes before. It's easier to see your proposed edits here. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks :) @Kablam

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `position:absolute` for the `----` to make it out of the `<a>` flow and also `position:relative` to the parent `<a>` element.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.wrap a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap p {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrap a:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.wrap a::before {
  content: '----';
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: -30px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.wrap a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>These links do not have the pointer-events: none; property</p>
  <br>
  <a href="#">link text one</a>
  <a href="#">link text two</a>
  <a href="#">link text three</a>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <p>These do have pointer-events: none; yet their behaviour is the same as with the block above.</p>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="pointerevents">link text one</a>
  <a href="#" class="pointerevents">link text two</a>
  <a href="#" class="pointerevents">link text three</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I see! This works, however it also involves a lot of setting margins and positions. I'll implement it like this for now, but I'm still hoping to find out why `pointer-events: none;` does not do what I expect it to do.

Comment: @Kablam if you use `pointer-events:none` without `position:absolute`, it will do nothing because `:before` is inside the `<a>` resulting total width of `<a>` will be `inner-text+:before`....using `position:absolute` make the element out of the flow and `width` of `<a>` will be the only inner text `width` and in that case `pointer-events:none` will work

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation!